# Bash: failed to read from a pipe

Tags: bash

On my Linux system, I want to generate a MD5 check sum and save it to a variable. The command to generate check sum is:

```
$ md5sum myfile.zip
```

And the output is:

```
060906cec6fd1037ff275d928f96b419  myfile.zip
```

I want to pipe this output into a `read` command like so:

```
$ md5sum myfile.zip | read sum filename
```

However, that does not seem to work: the variables `sum` and `filename` remains undefined. I worked around this problem by redirecting the output into a file, then read it back:

```
$ md5sum myfile.zip > tempfile
$ read sum filename < tempfile
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it? I appreciate your answers and comments.

Comment: The *already answered* question does not address my question. The comments from Inian and M. Nejat Aydin do. If you create the answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: It does address your question. The accepted answer shows why and how to use process substitution here, and even offers alternatives.

Comment: I take back: it does addressed my question. Thank you, @oguzismail

Comment: Try `read sum filename <<<$( md5sum myfile.zip )`. Here the read command is *not* executed in a subshell.

Comment: @Wiimm That also works. Thank you.